# SQL Group by MAX(Date)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following query. There are many inspectiondates for each driver license number. So the records can be as follows:

```
InspectionDate         DriverLicenseNumber
2010-01-02 00:00:00         123
2010-01-05 00:00:00         123 
2011-01-05 00:00:00         345 


  SELECT 
MAX(InspectionDate),
DriverLicenseNumber
FROM #Test
 GROUP BY DriverLicenseNumber
```

Why do I still get multiple multiple dates and for the same driver license number?

Thanks

Comment: What's the type of the DriverLicenseNumber column. Might there be spaces/non-printing characters included in there?

Comment: `GROUP BY` only returns one row per `DriverLicenseNumber` there must be something else going on.

Comment: That's what I thought. The DriverLicenseNumber is a VARCHAR(25) and the values that are duplicating are exaclty the same.

Comment: @user. Can you add `CAST(DriverLicenseNumber as varbinary(25))` to the `SELECT` list and see if there are any differences between numbers that appear the same?

Comment: Yea, I was passing the data to excel which was taking away the 00 in front of the license numbers so when I did a duplicate check it was saying these were duplicates. The VarBinary helped thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and it should test Damien's thought...

```
SELECT
  MAX(InspectionDate),
  CAST(DriverLicenseNumber AS INT)
FROM
  #Test
GROUP BY
  CAST(DriverLicenseNumber AS INT)
```

Or possibly this...

```
SELECT
  MAX(InspectionDate),
  LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(DriverLicenseNumber)))
FROM
  #Test
GROUP BY
  LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(DriverLicenseNumber)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code illustrates that this is not actually an issue, like Martin said above, there must be something else going on.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    a DATETIME,
    id INT
)

INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('20100102', 123)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('20100105', 123)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('20110105', 345)

SELECT MAX(a), id 
FROM #test
GROUP BY id

DROP TABLE #test
```

Answer (score 1):

just change DriverLicenseNumber to integer in your table and then your query will work as it is.